# Difference between AndroidX Transition library (androidx.transition) and the Android Transition Framework (android.transition)

Tags: android-support-library, androidx, android-transitions

What is the difference between androidx.transition and android.transition?

From https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion, it says that androidx.transition is AndroidX Transition library, while android.transition is Android Transition Framework.

So I guess the former is part of the new AndroidX and the latter is part of the Android Support Library?

But my key questions are:

1. What are the differences between the two in terms of features?
2. Which one should I be using?